# Forwarding `impl From` param to specialized function

Tags: rust

So I have some type

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: u32,
    pub baz: u32,
}

impl From<(u32, u32)> for Foo {
    fn from(foo: (u32, u32)) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar: foo.0,
            baz: foo.1,
        }
    }
}
```

My aim is to create a function that would receive something that implements `From<(u32, u32)>` and will forward it further to function expecting either `Foo` or `(u32, u32)`. So it should be something like this

```
pub fn print(val: impl From<(u32, u32)>) {
    print_foo(val.into());
    print_tuple(val.into())
}

pub fn print_tuple(t: (u32, u32)) {
    println!("Tuple: {:?}", t);
}

pub fn print_foo(foo: Foo) {
    println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
}
```

Unfortunately this will cause an error:

```
the trait `From<impl From<(u32, u32)>>` is not implemented for `Foo`
the trait `From<impl From<(u32, u32)>>` is not implemented for `(u32, u32)`
```

As I understand this wraps the `impl From<_>` with `From` due to `into()` call.

My question is how to reach the goal of having a function that can receive either tuple or struct that can be constructed from it and pass it further to specialized functions.

Comment: Normally you'd express this as `impl Into<...>`. You could also add a whole new trait `X` and apply it to both `(u32,u32)` and `Foo` such that you can do `impl X` instead. The trait then delegates to the appropriate `print`, or even better, you'd just have some kind of `impl Display` for that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`impl From<T>` is a pretty useless type to receive values of, it could be anything but all that `From` lets us do is create *new* items of the same type, not use the value we have in any meaningful way. What you want instead is use an `Into` implementation:

```rust
pub fn print<T: Into<(u32, u32)> + Into<Foo> + Clone>(val: T) {
    print_foo(val.clone().into());
    print_tuple(val.into())
}
```

Note since you want to pass the same value twice you have to either add a `Copy` or `Clone` bound as well or require `for<'a> &'a T: Into<Foo>` instead.

Comment: Not entirely useless, one common use case is to create generic numbers.